# How to click event on google widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using **Google Widget popup**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ozee.png)

**When I click on any option APPLE or GOOGLE it can not be tracked click event.**

```
 $('#addeventatc1-google').click(function(){
    let name = $('.speaker-name1').text(); 
    console.log(name);
});
```

How to get click event using **jquery**
Button Code is

```
<span class="ateappleical" id="addeventatc1-appleical" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Apple</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all.
I have figure it out. Now I am using this.

```
$(document).on("click",".addeventatc .addeventatc_dropdown 
span",function() {
let popupItem = $(this).text();
let speakerName = 
$(this).parent().parent().siblings('.name').text();
   updateTracking(speakerName ,popupItem );
});
```